# Как выравнить блоки по центру страницы?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, bootstrap

Здраствуйте)

Я начинаю изучать веб-разработку и наткнулся на проблему.
Почему-то блок не стоит по центру сможете помочь?
Вот изображение как оно выглядит:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfQmk.png]

Код html(Bootstrap 4):

```
<div id="clients" class="container-fluid mb-5 position-relative justify-content-center">
  <div class="row wow fadeIn">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-4 wow fadeInLeft d-block">
      <img src="img/otis-logo.png" alt="kone" style="margin-top: 200px;"><br>
      <img src="img/schindler-logo.png" alt="Thyssenkrupp" style="margin-top: 120px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4 d-flex justify-content-center wow fadeIn">
      <h1 id="Brands">Brands we work with</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4 wow fadeInRight">
      <img src="img/kone-logo.png" alt="kone" style="margin-top: 185px;"><br>
      <img src="img/thyssenkrupp-logo.png" alt="Thyssenkrupp" style="margin-top: 110px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Brands {
  color: #3c3c3b;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: Gilroy Black;
  margin-top: 130px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="clients" class="container-fluid mb-5 position-relative justify-content-center">
```

может стоит убрать из строки значение **mb-5** ?
или я не так понял какой именно блок

Comment: я хочу чтобы все изображение и текст по центру страницы были

Answer (score 0):

как то так ?

```
https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/dyMbGbV
```

```css
#Brands {
  color: #3c3c3b;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: Gilroy Black;
  margin-top: 130px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: scale(-1);
}
  
.direction{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="clients" class="container-fluid mb-5 position-relative justify-content-center">
  <div class="row wow fadeIn direction">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-4 wow fadeInLeft d-block">
      <img src="img/otis-logo.png" alt="kone" style="margin-top: 200px;"><br>
      <img src="img/schindler-logo.png" alt="Thyssenkrupp" style="margin-top: 120px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4 d-flex justify-content-center wow fadeIn">
      <h1 id="Brands">Brands we work with</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-4 wow fadeInRight">
      <img src="img/kone-logo.png" alt="kone" style="margin-top: 185px;"><br>
      <img src="img/thyssenkrupp-logo.png" alt="Thyssenkrupp" style="margin-top: 110px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```